# Date Transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I really need some help with this code. I have to write code using the input file `Unit 5 Dates.txt`, containing dates in the form `yyyy/mm/dd`, read all lines into a list, find the earliest and the latest dates and print, then transform the date string into the form `July 12, 2014` and print all dates.

I have written the code and it's working fine, but I don't know how to transform the date into the form `November 10, 2015`.

```
def main():
    dateList = get_list()
    dateMin = find_min(dateList)
    print(dateMin)
    dateMax = find_max(dateList)
    print(dateMax)
    print ()
    print_dates(dateList)
    #changeDate = date_changer(dateList) 

def get_list():
    infile = open("Unit 5 Dates.txt", 'r')
    dateList = infile.readlines()
    infile.close()
    return dateList

def find_min(dateList):
    dateMin = dateList[0]
    for index in range(len(dateList)):
        dateList[index] = dateList[index].rstrip("\n")
        if dateList[index] < dateMin:
            dateMin = dateList[index]

    return "The earlest date in the file is: " + dateMin

def find_max(dateList):
    dateMax = dateList[0]
    for index in range(len(dateList)):
        if dateList[index] > dateMax:
            dateMax = dateList[index]

    return"The latest date in the file is: " + dateMax


def print_dates(dateList):
    print("This is the list of dates")
    for index in range(len(dateList)):
        print(dateList[index])

main()
```

What your told me, I have do that, but it not working. What if i want to read it from a txt file name `Unit 5 Dates.txt`, that already have all the dates in it. For example, if you look at my code, I create a value returning function called `get_list`, and then I `define` it and open the `Unit 5 dates.txt`, file and read all the dates from the txt file.

Here Iis what I have so far. I have have create a create a function called `date_chnage` and also I have define the function. But when I run the code it give me a error message..

```
def date_changer(dateList):

import datetime as datechanger

infile = open("Unit 5 Dates.txt", 'r')   

print("This is the list of dates")
for index in range(len(dateList)):
    dateList = datechanger.datetime.strptime(datechanger, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
    print (date.strftime("%B %d, %Y")) 

main()
```

Here is the error it's giving me

`File "/Users/mohamedkeita/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/School/2015:2016 School/Python/Unit 5/KeitaM_Unit 5 copy.py", line 18, in main
    changeDate = date_changer(dateList)
  File "/Users/mohamedkeita/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/School/2015:2016 School/Python/Unit 5/KeitaM_Unit 5 copy.py", line 70, in date_changer
    dateList = datechanger.datetime.strptime(datechanger, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
TypeError: must be str, not module`

Comment: You should look into `datetime`.

Comment: You could also, of course, simply use a list of month names and a lookup, but there are date library functions that will do it too, as @jon says.

Comment: What your told me, I have do that, but it not working. What if i want to read it from a txt file name `Unit 5 Dates.txt`, that already have all the dates in it. For example, if you look at my code, I create a value returning function called `get_list`, and then I define it and open the `Unit 5 dates.txt`, file and read all the dates from the txt file.

Comment: What your told me, I have do that, but it not working. What if i want to read it from a txt file name `Unit 5 Dates.txt`, that already have all the dates in it. For example, if you look at my code, I create a value returning function called `get_list`, and then I define it and open the `Unit 5 dates.txt`, file and read all the dates from the txt file.

Comment: The first argument in `datetime.strptime` needs to be a string, such as `"2015/11/11"` You are using a module. Write a loop that will read the dates  from a file and then use each string in turn.

Comment: You also should not rename `datetime` to `datechanger`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime as dt

dates='''\
2015/11/11
1941/12/07
1776/07/04'''

for ds in dates.splitlines():
    date=dt.datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y/%m/%d').date()
    print(date.strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
```

Prints:

```
November 11, 2015
December 07, 1941
July 04, 1776
```

You can use a datetime date for max and min as well:

```
>>> max(dates.splitlines(), key=lambda l: dt.datetime.strptime(l, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
'2015/11/11'
>>> min(dates.splitlines(), key=lambda l: dt.datetime.strptime(l, '%Y/%m/%d').date())
'1776/07/04'
```

While I am using `dates.splitlines()` in the example, that could be another source -- such as a file.

In the case where you have YYYY/MM/DD as digits in a string, you can also just use [lexicographical sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to determine min/max as well:

```
>>> max(dates.splitlines())
'2015/11/11'
>>> min(dates.splitlines())
'1776/07/04'
```

If you need to convert or validate a date, use datetime.